# Oracle Client: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, oracleclient

Why we need to install Oracle client on the web-server for ODP.NET connectivity, why can't we add only Oracle.DataAccess.dll reference and do the work done.

We have a requirement where we are inserting the record into oracle from Microsoft Dynamics CRM. When I tried to the insert I got above error, so after installing Oracle Client on the development web-server, error got resolved. Now the problem is we need a justification for Production deployment that why we need to install Oracle Client on production web-server.

Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle.DataAccess.dll uses a number of unmanaged dlls, so you can't just add a reference to it. You need the client installed.

The managed ODAC only needs the referenced dll, are you able to use this instead ?

Comment: Thanks Julian, yes got to know about this unmanaged dlls which will be added after installing client on the server.